# WCF SSL Rest based web service with basic authetication

Tags: wcf, rest, ssl, basic-authentication, webhttpbinding

I have a simple WCF REST based service deployed (development ofcourse) using SSL. I am trying to make it work with basic authentication but quite frankly am getting nowhere with it.

IIS 6.0
REST based - Using webHttpBinding

Here is what my web.config looks like ... just the relevant portions:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ThisTestService.MyTestServiceBehavior"
        name="ThisTestService.MyTestService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Secure" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" contract="ThisTestService.IMyTestService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="Secure" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ThisTestService.MyTestServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Secure">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have Anonymous authentication turned off in IIS on the virtual directory for the WCF service and Basic authentication is turned on.

When I try to access it say using https://localhost/ThisTestService/MyTestService.svc, I cannot get to it. It gives the "Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].".

I've googled a lot but so far all my attempts to understand and fix the issue have been in vain. If I use anonymous authentication then I have no issues however I need to use basic authentication.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In IIS Manager, have you edited bindings for the web site to make https available?

Comment: Hi ... are you refering to using the adsutils.vbs script?

Comment: Please see my article '[WCF: SOAP/REST + SSL + Basic authentification + IIS](http://vgolovchenko.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/wcf-soaprest-ssl-basic-authentification-iis/)'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on https for the virtual directory in which you are hosting the service. (As explained in the last para of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx)